# Inject Injectable Classes from Same File in Another Class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

## Problem

So I wrote a `Database` class in database.ts, which I'd like to have two injectable members, `Document` and `List`, which are both in the same file. Due to the organization of the project, they must remain in the same file. After trying tirelessly, I've been unable to make the `document` and `list` non-null members of `Database`, or inject these classes through `Database`'s constructor. Errors include `Can't resolve all parameters for Database`, `Can't get document of undefined`, and so on. Here's my attempt.

## Attempt

`database.ts`:

*`Database` Class (Multiple Attempts)*

```
@Injectable()
export class Database {
      constructor(@Inject(Document) public document:Document, @Inject(List) public list:List) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class Database {
      public document:Document;
      public list:List;
}
```

*`Document` Class*

```
@Injectable()
class Document {
      constructor(private events:Events, private db: AngularFireDatabase, public auth:Auth, public utility:Utility) {}
      ...
}
```

*`List` Class*

```
@Injectable()
class List {
      constructor(private events:Events, private db: AngularFireDatabase, public auth:Auth, public utility:Utility) {}
      ...
}
```

## Notes

I'd like to find a solution where I can reference the database class and it's subclasses as follows:
`this.database.document.function()` and `this.database.list.function()`.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try without using the @Inject(...) stuff in the constructor? Also, did you register all three classes via providers?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Good questions; yes I tried doing so, and I only have `Database` as a provider in my module, since doing so for all three would cause a circular dependency error.

Comment: All three need to be listed as providers (that is why you mark them with @Injectable). If there is a circular reference issue then some other thing is going on since the database is dependent on those two and there is no dependency in the other direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem solved!

Following Daniel W Strimpel's suggestion, I **added `Document` and `List` as imports** into my `app.module.ts` as follows:

`import { Database, Document, List } from '../classes/database';`

and **registered the above classes as Providers**.

I simply make sure I don't import import `Document` or `List` individually into files that use these two classes but, rather, import `Database` for all the functionality of both classes. Hope this helps.